# Computation of a quotient group in the direct sum of three copies of Z

Tags: group-theory, quotient-group, direct-product

My question is simple: How to compute the quotient group
$$\frac{\langle(1,1,0),(0,0,1)\rangle}{\langle(1,1,-1),(1,1,1)\rangle}$$
of subgroups of $\mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z$? The answer would be graet if each of the steps are explained.

This is my try: Letting $v=(1,1,0)$ and $w=(0,0,1)$, then the problem is to compute
$$\frac{\langle v,w\rangle}{\langle v+w, v-w \rangle}.$$
I wish this is isomorphic to the quotient
$$\frac{\mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z}{\langle (1,1),(1,-1) \rangle} \simeq \mathbb Z_2.$$

How to verify this argument? Or is there any other good argument? I want to know as many ways as possible. The answer may contain any undergraduate level mathematics.

Thank you.

Comment: Please share your thoughts on the problem.

Comment: Also define "compute". You want to represent it (up to isomorphism) as a product of cyclic groups?

Comment: Added more details, thanks for your tips.

Comment: I think if you put in the extra step that $\langle v+w,v-w \rangle=\langle 2v,v-w\rangle$ then everything is absolutely clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition of quotient:

\begin{alignat}{1}
\frac{\langle(1,1,0),(0,0,1)\rangle}{\langle(1,1,-1),(1,1,1)\rangle} &= \{(i,i,j)+\langle(1,1,-1),(1,1,1)\rangle\mid i,j\in\Bbb Z\} \\
&= \{(i,i,j)+\{(k+l,k+l,-k+l)\mid k,l\in \Bbb Z\}\mid i,j\in\Bbb Z\} \\
&= \{\{(i+k+l,i+k+l,j-k+l)\mid i,j,k,l\in\Bbb Z\}\} \\
&= \{\{(m,m,j-m+2l+i)\mid i,j,l,m\in\Bbb Z\}\} \\
&= \{(m,m,j-m)+\{(0,0,2l+i)\mid i,l\in \Bbb Z\}\mid j,m\in\Bbb Z\} \\
&= \{(m,m,j-m)+\{(0,0,r)\mid r\in \Bbb Z\}\mid j,m\in\Bbb Z\} \\
&= \{(m,m,j-m)+\langle(0,0,1)\rangle\mid j,m\in\Bbb Z\} \\
&= \frac{\langle(1,1,-1),(0,0,1)\rangle}{\langle(0,0,1)\rangle}
\end{alignat}

Now, $\varphi\colon \langle(1,1,-1),(0,0,1)\rangle\to \langle(1,1,0)\rangle$ defined by $(m,m,j-m)\mapsto (m,m,0)$ is a surjective homomorphism with kernel $\operatorname{ker}\varphi=\langle(0,0,1)\rangle$, whence (First Homomorphism Theorem):

$$\frac{\langle(1,1,-1),(0,0,1)\rangle}{\langle(0,0,1)\rangle}\cong \langle(1,1,0)\rangle$$

Finally, $\langle(1,1,0)\rangle\cong \Bbb Z_2$; in fact, consider the mapping $(m,m,0)\mapsto 0$ if $m$ is even and $(m,m,0)\mapsto 1$ if $m$ is odd.

(Remark. I wasn't smart enough to use the FHT directly on the first quotient, but it's certainly possible.)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to write this group is as $\langle u,v|uv,uv^{-1}\rangle$.

The Smith normal form can be used.  We start with $\begin{pmatrix} 1&1\\1&-1\end{pmatrix}$, since we have two generators and two relators. This leads to $\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&2\end{pmatrix}$, implying that we do indeed have $\Bbb Z_2$.